# Копирование файла и его извлечение на сервер через bash

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Нужна помощь в доработке скрипта. Нужно, чтобы при запуске

```
./script servername filename
```

Происходило копирование файла и его извлечение на сервере. Привожу первоначальный код скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash

dev="deploy@1.2.3.4"
test="deploy@1.2.3.5"

way="/var/www/builds/"
front="/var/www/html/test1/"
file="$way/front_build_$1.tar.gz"
key="/var/www/conf/id_rsa"

scp -i $key $file $test:/var/www/html/test/
ssh -i $key $test "tar xvf /var/www/html/test/front_build_$1.tar.gz
 --overwrite-dir --exclude='./cache' --exclude='./logs' -C $front"
```

и после предложенных изменений:

```
#!/bin/bash

dev="deploy@1.2.3.4"
test="deploy@1.2.3.5"

way="/var/www/builds/"
repo="/var/www/html/$2/"
file="$way/front_build_$3.tar.gz"
key="/var/www/conf/id_rsa"


case "$1" in
  dev)
    server="deploy@1.2.3.4"
  ;;
  test)
    server="deploy@1.2.3.5"
  ;;
  *)
    echo "первый параметр должен быть либо dev, либо test"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac

scp -i $key $file $server:/var/www/html/test/
ssh -i $key $server "tar xvf /var/www/html/test/front_build_$3.tar.gz --overwrite-dir --exclude='./cache' --exclude='./logs' -C $repo"
```

Сейчас копирование и извлечение происходит только на сервер `test`. А мне нужно, чтобы он при запуске понимал сервера, которые в нем описаны. К примеру.

```
./script dev 10
```

и, соответсвтенно

```
./script test 10
```

Нужна ваша помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

первый параметр (имя сервера) можно обрабатывать, например, так (одновременно присваивая нужные значения и другим переменным):

```
case "$1" in
  dev)
    server="deploy@1.2.3.4"
    path=/путь/на/dev/сервере
  ;;
  test)
    server="deploy@1.2.3.5"
    path=/путь/на/test/сервере
  ;;
  *)
    echo "первый параметр должен быть либо dev, либо test"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

соответственно, далее в скрипте надо исправить обращения к `$test` на обращения к `$server`.

использование позиционных параметров (`$номер`) где-либо в теле скрипта (помимо начальной обработки параметров) приводит лишь к сложностям в последующих модификациях (изменения количества и/или порядка параметров).

поэтому рекомендую в начале присвоить значение параметра `$2` (номер сборки, как я понял) какой-нибудь именной переменной, и затем использовать обращения именно к ней:

```
sborka=$2
...
... /var/www/html/test/front_build_${sborka}.tar.gz ...
```

**обновление**

хорошим тоном была бы также проверка количества параметров. что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
usage() {
  echo "использование: $0 [dev|test] номер-сборки"
}

[ $# -eq 2 ] || { usage; exit 1; }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ваш ответ. Сейчас буду пробывать.

Comment: я вносил исправления/дополнения, вероятно, в то время, пока вы читали. обновите страницу и перечитайте, пожалуйста. если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его. пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: Обыграл с кейсом. Я получил то что мне нужно было. Спасибо вам огромнейшее. Теперь мне захотелось чтобы я делал так ./script server path file. Тоесть сейчас у меня стоит путь к одной папке. А задача такая, на каждом сервере разный путь распаковки. Вот нужно это обыграть с 2м параметром при вызове скрипта.

Comment: @JamesMaynard, никаких сложностей: в начале скрипта обрабатывайте параметры (их у вас будет уже три: `$1` будет содержать "server", `$2` будет содержать "path", $3 будет содержать "file"), присваивая значения именным переменным, дальше в теле скрипта используйте эти переменные в нужных местах.

Comment: @JamesMaynard, *на каждом сервере разный путь* — определитесь, пожалуйста, что вы хотите передавать параметром: имя сервера или путь на сервере.

Comment: В предыдущем комментарии вы всё правильно поняли. Мне не понятен этот момент. Добавляю новый путь - fronttest="var/www/html/test2"
изменяю переменные в скрипте ssh -i $key $server "tar xvf /var/www/html/test/front_build_$3.tar.gz --overwrite-dir --exclude='./cache' --exclude='./logs' -C $2" Получаю вывод при запросе ./script.sh dev front 10 front_build_101.tar.gz              100% 8476KB   8.3MB/s   8.3MB/s   00:00
tar: front: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Почему то не отрабатывает $2 переменная.

Comment: во-первых, как я уже писал, не используйте позиционные параметры внутри скрипта. в начале скрипта сразу сохраните их значения в нужные переменные, и затем обращайтесь к этим переменным. во-вторых, добавьте, пожалуйста, в текст вопроса вашу новую редакцию скрипта — в комментариях нет разбивки на строки и потому непонятно, о чём речь.

Comment: Отредактировал тему.

Comment: вы передаёте вторым параметром слово "front", а затем используете это слово в команде `tar ... -C $2`. опция `-С` у программы `tar` в данном случае указывает, в какой каталог следует распаковывать файлы (без неё распаковка будет происходить в текущий каталого, в вашем случае, это будет домашний каталог на машине, к которой подключаетесь). вероятно, каталога "front" нет в домашнем каталоге на той машине.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромнейшее. Разобрался. Всё заработало. Сейчас исправлю тему. Вопрос а если нужно будет на каком то из серверов сменить путь скажем на /var/www/reository/front как это реализовать с переменными?

Comment: я обновил ответ, добавив в первый блок кода пример присвоения нескольких переменных в операторе `case`.

Comment: Я не правильно выразился. Я имел ввиду путь извлечения архива.

Comment: подставьте в нужное место значение нужной переменной. чтобы избежать смешения с последующими буквами, лучше не в виде `$name`, а в виде `${name}`.

Comment: мне нужно чтоб было так ./script dev front-temp 10 где front-temp это /var/www/test/reository/front и опять же если например нужно  ./script dev front 10 это /var/www/html/test1 и на другом серваке аналогично. это папки куда будет извлекаться архив.

Comment: пример присвоения я привёл. подставляйте в нужном месте скрипта значение нужной переменной.

Comment: я так понимаю что  я должен добавить в скрипт ещё один путь. front-temp="/var/www/test/reository/$3 и где то задать переменную? как тогда обыграть момент -C $repo" тут получается должна быть переменная которая будет понимать что нужно менять путь извлечения. я чет запутался.

Comment: замените упоминания конкретного пути в двух последних строках на переменную `$path`. а значение этой переменной присваивайте, как предложено в ответе. извините, но это последний комментарий, который я оставляю под этим вопросом.