# Название файла на основе параметров скрипта

Tags: linux, bash

Добрый день. Есть скрипт на баше. Нужно, чтобы в нем имя файла создавалось на основе параметров.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/var/www/builds/front_build_$3.tar.gz"
repo="/var/www/html/$2/"
key="/var/www/conf/id_rsa"

case "$1" in
  dev)
    server="deploy@1.2.3.4"
  ;;
  test)
    server="deploy@1.2.3.5"
  ;;
  *)
    echo "первый параметр должен быть либо dev, либо test"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac


scp -i $key $file $server:/var/www/archives/

ssh -i $key $server "tar xvf /var/www/archives/front_build_$3.tar.gz --overwrite-dir --exclude='./cache' --exclude='./logs' -C $repo"
```

Например:

```
./script dev front 10
```

Если, допустим, мы шлем на дев сервер, имя фала будет `build_front_dev_10.tar.gz`.

А если, например:

```
./script test front 10
```

тогда имя файла должно быть `build_front_test_10.tar.gz`.

Сейчас имя файла формируется, исходя из номера сборки. А нужно, чтобы исходя из всех параметров. Надеюсь, внятно выразил свою идею.

Задача усложнаяется тем что нельзя задать путь извлечения типа ./script test front/folder 10 тогда скрипт отругает что нет такого файла.

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? У Вас уже используется номер сборки, который указан третьим аргументом - отлично, добавьте еще аргументы `$1` и `$2` в строку `file` по аналогии с `$3`. Или необходимо входные параметры каким-либо образом преобразовывать?

Comment: Задача усложнаяется тем что нельзя задать путь извлечения типа ./script test front/folder 10 тогда скрипт отругает что нет такого файла.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите тестовый пример. В варианте `./script test front/folder 10` непонятно, что необходимо извлекать из второго аргумента. Может быть, он должен выглядеть как `path/to/front`?

Comment: пример ./script test front 10 - получаем извлечение в /../front/ и название файла build_front_10.tar.gz А если допустим этот же архив нужно извлеч в другую папку. Как быть?

Comment: Изначальный пример понятен, не понятно, что делать с front/folder. Приведите, пожалуйста, такой пример: какое имя вы хотите задавать, и в какую папку нужно извлекать файл?

Comment: к примеру на сервере dev путь для извлечения будет в /var/www/html на сервере test путь будет /var/www/test/ и нужно чтобы при запросе скрипт понимал что вот такой то архив на этом сервере ложить сюда, а на этом сервере туда. и путь может быть разный в пределах папки.

Comment: Сил уже нету, честное слово. Вы говорите "к примеру", приводите туманное объяснение и хотите скрипт. Скажите **конкретно**, какие варианты параметра могут быть, и какое итоговое имя файла с директорией, куда его класть, в **каждом из этих случаев** должны быть. Поймите, нужно **четкое и формальное** описания правила, по которому вы ставите имя файла в соответствие переданным параметрам.

Comment: @VadimShender, +1, а то получается не ответ на вопрос, а консультирование в реальном времени по меняющимся требованиям.

Comment: Коллеги прошу не пинать меня. Вот как стояла задача.   $script.sh master front 10

где
* master - это одна из основных веток репы
* front - это название репы
* 10 - номер билда

Из этих параметров мы формируем откуда и куда будет залит релиз,
соответственно:

dev ветка - это dev сервер
master ветка - это test сервер


на основе второго и третьего параметра строим имя билда:
front_build_101.tar.gz

 билды лежат в /var/www/builds/ на dev сервере.

Далее, скрипт копирует архив билда на удаленный сервер и там
разархивирует в папку.

Comment: Вас никто не пинает. Сейчас хоть стала яснее суть, но конкретики для написания **конкретного** скрипта все равно не хватает. Опишите 1. точное правило, как строится имя (а то у вас опять имя на основе второго и третьего параметров -- front_build_101.tar.gz, а ранее в вопросе фигруировало имя на основе всех трех парметров build_front_dev_10.tar.gz); 2. конкретные пути, куда класть архив в каждом из случаев dev и test (сейчас у вас кладется в /var/www/html/$2, то есть путь зависит от второго параметра, который равен front в ваших примерах). Без всей этой конкретики вам никто ничем не поможет.

Comment: имя должно строиться так front_dev_build_10, front_test_build_10, исходя из запроса ./script dev front 10. пути для 2х этих серверов одинаковые, добавиться ещё один сервер на котором путь будет другой - какой я пока не знаю.

Comment: @VadimShender, для спраки: этот вопрос — продолжение [эпопеи](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435055/178576).

Comment: Ну вот, имя вы уже формировать умеете. А пути, если отличаются, можно устанавливать в зависимости от `test`/`dev` там же, где вы устанавливаете значения переменной `server`. Всего-то и делов.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге правильного ответа не нашел и решил передалть скрипт. Вот что мне нужно было.

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=$1
REPONAME=$2
BNUMBER=$3

FNAME="`echo $REPONAME`_`echo $BRANCH`_build_` echo $BNUMBER`.tar.gz"
FFROM=/var/www/builds/$FNAME
REPO=/var/www/html/$REPONAME/
KEY=/var/www/conf/id_rsa

echo $REPO

case "$1" in
  'dev')
    SERVER="deploy@1.2.3.4"
  ;;
  'test')
    SERVER="deploy@1.2.3.5"
  ;;
  *)
    echo "первый параметр должен быть либо dev, либо test"
    exit 1
  ;;
esac


scp -i $KEY $FFROM $SERVER:/var/www/archives/

ssh -i $KEY $SERVER "tar xvf /var/www/archives/$FNAME --overwrite-dir --exclude='./cache' --exclude='./logs' -C $REPO"
```

Спасибо всем кто участвовал и помог советом.

Answer (score 0):

Просто поменяйте везде `/var/www/builds/front_build_$3.tar.gz` на `/var/www/builds/build_$2_$1_$3.tar.gz`.

Comment: Задача усложнаяется тем что нельзя задать путь извлечения типа ./script test front/folder 10 тогда скрипт отругает что нет такого файла.

Comment: В таком случае, по вашему же описанию, имя получается `/var/www/builds/build_front/folder_test_10.tar.gz`. Правило описано вами, и все работает в соответствии с ним. Каким на самом деле должно быть имя в случае указания `front/folder`?

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
file="/var/www/builds/front_build_$3.tar.gz"
```

на

```
file="/var/www/builds/build_$2_$1_$3.tar.gz"
```

и

```
ssh -i $key $server "tar xvf /var/www/archives/front_build_$3.tar.gz --overwrite-dir --exclude='./cache' --exclude='./logs' -C $repo"
```

на

```
ssh -i $key $server "tar xvf /var/www/archives/build_$2_$1_$3.tar.gz --overwrite-dir --exclude='./cache' --exclude='./logs' -C $repo"
```

Comment: Задача усложнаяется тем что нельзя задать путь извлечения типа ./script test front/folder 10 тогда скрипт отругает что нет такого файла.